# Image displays differently in XAML vs. C#

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to show an image in a Grid

[Only the image shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9REa.png) when I use this XAML:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/O.png"
       Grid.Column="6"
       Grid.Row="5"/>
```

In C# it shows the picture with a border outside:

```
Image img = new Image();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/O.png", UriKind.Relative);
img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
img.Source = bi;
Grid.SetColumn(img, 6);
Grid.SetRow(img, 7);
gridGameBoard.Children.Add(img);

Image img1 = new Image();
img1.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/X.png", UriKind.Relative));
Grid.SetColumn(img1, 4);
Grid.SetRow(img1, 4);
gridGameBoard.Children.Add(img1);
```

I tried googling to find any differences between BitmapImage and other Image types but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Stretch` property of your `Image`. In XAML, you do not define it, so a default value of `Uniform` is used. In C# code you have `img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;`

My guess is that the border is in the image, but in the C# code with `Fill` the image is scaled down, the XAML variant with `Uniform` scales up the image and centers it so the border is not visible.

Comment: No, I had fixed that to Uniform or fixed UniformToFill both in XAML and in C# but it still has a border



If I open that image in Window Viewer or Paint, I don't show border

Comment: This is that image
http://s1.postimg.org/5h711j3gr/image.png
http://s1.postimg.org/67zr7b5u3/image.png

And the viewer : http://s7.postimg.org/trn6czim3/Screenshot_36.png

Comment: OK, I had know that, because I had put that image in to a for loop .
So It's loop many times, and so that, It's bold 
http://codepad.org/wUmkMb9B